# DDL generation with Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, ddl, hbm2ddl

When you write an application that uses Hibernate, and that you define your model starting with classes, how do you generate the script that contains the DDL to setup the database?

I know there is a Hibernate tool `hbm2ddl` that may be used for that but I can't find it for the latest version of Hibernate (4.1.6).

Also, in the developers guide (v4.1.6), I've seen there is a tool called `SchemaExport` that is used to generate DDL from mappings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) will most likely do what you want.  According to their [manual page on hibernate](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/hibernate), it will do a better job than hbm2ddl - I have not used hbm2ddl so I can't back up their claim.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be a great tool

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate automatically creates the tables if you set

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```